# Error calling Exchange Powershell command remotely in code (c#)

Tags: powershell, sdk

I'm posting the problem and the solution. I would have loved to know this half a day ago.

### The error:

> "The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside
>   the overrides of the BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing
>   methods, and only from that same thread. Validate that the cmdlet
>   makes these calls correctly, or please contact Microsoft Support
>   Services."

### The bug:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cp in args.CP)
{
   command.AddCommand(args.Command);
   command.AddParameter(cp.Key, cp.Value);
}
```

### Solved, Solution:

```
command.AddCommand(args.Command);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> cp in args.CP)
{
    command.AddParameter(cp.Key, cp.Value);
}
```

The error still doesn't make since to me. I went off on a tangent looking at PS async stuff.

Hope this helps others...

Comment: You should move the solution into an answer.

Comment: How? I don't see a way without posting at least 80 chars.

Comment: There should be a text box right above a "Post Your Answer" button. On StackOverflow, it's perfectly acceptable to post an answer to your own question and mark it as accepted.